# Node.JS - For Loop combined with .split() function does not console.log() new variable

Tags: javascript, node.js, for-loop, variables, split

i read on different sources about the for loop and i still have kind of trouble to get it. So i thought i ask here to get it explained by somebody else.

What the Problem?

i read a txt file into an array which contents multiple login data. The format is: login:passw
I want to split login:pw so i cann acces the login and password and store them in different var (let login and let passw)

What did i try?

I tried to loop through my whole array which contents currently 5 indexes and split them all in the same way so i can access login and password with different indexes.

The array is called mp

My code:

```
for (let i = 0; i < mp.lenght; i++) {
   let login = mp.split(":");
   console.log(login);
```

When i try to console log the new variable login, the programm is not loggin any yerrors, its just showing nothing. Not even undefined. if anybody has an idea why pls let me now!

Thanks

Comment: Why a loop ?
```let login = mp.split(':');
console.log(login);```

Comment: show us your text file contents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a small mistake in your code. You are calling the `split` method on the `array` not on `array element`.

Call the `split` method on `array element`.

And also there is a typo. it's `length` not `lenght`.

Try this.

```js
let mp = ["login1:pass1", "login2:pass2"];

for (let i = 0; i < mp.length; i++) {
    let login = mp[i].split(":");
    console.log(login);
 }
```

You could use `forEach` loop for simplicity.

```js
let mp = ["login1:pass1", "login2:pass2"];

mp.forEach( item => {
    let login = item.split(":");
    console.log(login);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! That make actuall sense! Now i got only the problem that it still splitting wrong:

[ 'testlogin@web.de' ]
[ 'passw\r\ntestlogin1@web.de' ]
[ 'passwd\r\ntestlogin2@web.de' ]
[ 'passwd' ]

Any idea how to split it correctly?

Comment: Could you add the sample input data .

Comment: I read a txt file which looks like this:
login:pass
login:pass
Login:pass
........

Then this is my code:

    let mp = fs.readFileSync("mp.txt", "utf8").split(":");

    for (i = 0; i < mp.length; i++) {
    let login = mp[i].split(":");
    console.log(login);
    }

And the Output is that:

[ 'testlogin@web.de' ]
[ '12345677\r\ntestlogin1@web.de' ]
[ '112383823\r\ntestlogin2@web.de' ]
[ '884844884' ]

Answer (score 1):

Because the mp variable is an array, not a record in that array.
Instead of: `let login = mp.split(":");`
Use: `let login = mp[i].split(":");`

Comment: Thanks! makes sense. Now i get these result as console.log(login);

[ 'testlogin@web.de' ]
[ '12345677\r\ntestlogin1@web.de' ]
[ '112383823\r\ntestlogin2@web.de' ]
[ '884844884' ]

Any idea how i can solve it?